# Apache Boot Log

Tags: ubuntu

If apache fails to load on ubuntu-server, where can I find the logs to find out why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these two files:

```
/var/log/apache2/error.log
/var/log/messages
```

Another thing you could do is run `$ apache2ctl configtest`. That will run a syntax check over your config files and should let you know if anything looks awry.

Answer (score 0):

The default logging location for Apache2 in Ubuntu server is /var/log/apache2